# Placeholder Date with ANGULAR date.now() doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datetime, angular-filters

In a web application I have an `input type="date"` and I'd like the user had the current date already default. So I used Angular because in pure js didn't work on phone (although in the browser worked). So this is the **html** part:

```
<body ng-app="app">    
<form ng-controller="DateController as dateCtrl"> 
<input type="date" id="date" value="{{value}}" ng-model="value" placeholder="dd-MM-yyyy">
</form>
</body>
```

and this is the **AngularJS** code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
 app.controller('DateController', ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter) {
$scope.value = $filter('date')(Date.now(), "dd-MM-yyyy"); 
}]);
```

Both Firefox and Chrome give me an error in console. But in Firefox it works, and in Chrome it doesn't work.
Chrome error:

> The specified value '{{value}}' does not conform to the required
>   format, 'yyyy-MM-dd'. 
>   angular.min-1.4.5.js:107 Error: [ngModel:datefmt]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/ngModel/datefmt?p0=08-02-2016
>       at Error (native)
>       at file:///mypath/js/angular.min-1.4.5.js:6:416
>       at Array. (file:///mypath/js/angular.min-1.4.5.js:165:14)
>       at Object. (file:///mypath/js/angular.min-1.4.5.js:264:75)
>       at m.$get.m.$digest (file:///mypath/js/angular.min-1.4.5.js:129:480)
>       at m.$get.m.$apply (file:///mypath/js/angular.min-1.4.5.js:133:113)
>       at file:///mypath/js/angular.min-1.4.5.js:19:479
>       at Object.e [as invoke] (file:///mypath/js/angular.min-1.4.5.js:39:96)
>       at d (file:///mypath/js/angular.min-1.4.5.js:19:400)
>       at yc (file:///mypath/js/angular.min-1.4.5.js:20:179)(anonymous
>   function) @ angular.min-1.4.5.js:107$get @
>   angular.min-1.4.5.js:80$get.m.$digest @
>   angular.min-1.4.5.js:130$get.m.$apply @
>   angular.min-1.4.5.js:133(anonymous function) @
>   angular.min-1.4.5.js:19e @ angular.min-1.4.5.js:39d @
>   angular.min-1.4.5.js:19yc @ angular.min-1.4.5.js:20Zd @
>   angular.min-1.4.5.js:19(anonymous function) @
>   angular.min-1.4.5.js:292m.Callbacks.j @
>   jquery.min.js:2m.Callbacks.k.fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2m.extend.ready
>   @ jquery.min.js:2J @ jquery.min.js:2 jquery.min.js:5
>
> The specified value '08-02-2016' does not conform to the required format,
>   'yyyy-MM-dd'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First of all, some engines do not support the Date.now function. ( as
  described in
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now)
  So you can just do with `$scope.value= new Date();` or `$scope.value=
  new Date(Date.now());`
- Second of all, the input type date is i think unformattable. It just
  takes the system default and applies that to the GUI. So you will just have to go with `<input type="date" id="date" ng-model="value" placeholder="dd-MM-yyyy">`

Answer (score 0):

This error in coming due to format issue of date.
you can do this by assigning date value to the scope variable
like this:   $scope.value = new Date ();

```
visit http://plnkr.co/edit/0WXlKM8xoBp4eBLovQ63?p=preview
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use input type date because it will not work on firefox